# Grouping matrix rows in terms of one column

Tags: matlab, matrix, parallel-processing, grouping, cell

First of all it is really hard for me to describe the problem really good but I'll try.

Say that we have matrix A

```
A = [23 1;
     45 1
     78 1
     86 1
     98 2
     1  2
     23 2
     14 3
     15 4
     85 4]
```

What I want as an output is

```
    B{1} = [23,45,78,86]
    B{2} = [98,1,23]
    B{3} = [14]
    B{4} = [15,85]
```

Bear in mind that the original A is a huge matrix, and I do not wanna do this with for loops. I would like to use functions that uses parallel processing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `accumarray` here:

```
B = accumarray(A(:,2),A(:,1),[],@(x){x},{});
```

If you know that `A` is sorted, and that there is no missing entry from the second column, you can also use `mat2cell`:

```
counts = histc(A(:,2),unique(A(:,2)));
B = mat2cell(A(:,1),counts);
```

Comment: hi, what if you can't use option#2 because there's one missing entry, but you want to copy all columns in A rather than just the first, so can't use accumarray?

Comment: @Jake: you can definitely use `accumarray`: `B = accumarray(A(:,2),(1:size(A,1))',[],@(x){A(x,:)},{});`. The trick is to pass an index vector to the accumulator.

Comment: Does that result in a matrix instead of a cell array?

Comment: @Jake: No, the curly brackets in the anonymous functions prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to do it. It uses a loop, but should be pretty quick because the cell array `B` is pre-allocated using the reverse index trick.

```
for key = fliplr(unique(A(:,2)'))
    ndx = A(:,2) == key;
    B{key} = A(ndx,1)';
end
```

Comment: that fliplr trick saved me 5 sec thank you. but I need more :D