# MatLab (or any other language) to convert a matrix or a csv to put 2nd column values to the same row if 1st column value is the same?

Tags: python, matlab, matrix

So for example I have

### 1st column |  2nd column

```
1             1
1             3
1             9
2             4
2             7
```

I want to convert it to

### 1st column | 2nd column | 3rd column | 4th column

```
1             1           3           9
2             4           7           3
```

The (3,4) element should be empty.

I can do it by Matlab using for and if but it takes too much time for huge data, so I need a more elegant and brilliant idea.

I prefer Matlab but other languages are ok. (I can export the matrix to csv or xlsx or txt and use the other languages, if that language can solve my problem.)

Thank you in advance!

**[Updates]**

If

```
      A = [2 3 234 ; 2 44 33; 2 12 22; 3 123 99; 3 1232 45; 5 224 57]
```

### 1st column |  2nd column | 3rd column

```
2             3          234
2             44         33
2             12         22
3             123        99
3             1232       45
5             224        57
```

then running

```
    [U ix iu] = unique(A(:,1) ); r= accumarray( iu, A(:,2:3), [], @(x) {x'} )
```

will show me the error

```
    Error using accumarray
    Second input VAL must be a vector with one element for each row in SUBS, or a
    scalar.
```

I want to make

### 1st col |  2nd col | 3rd col | 4th col | 5th col | 6th col| 7th col

```
2         3        234       44        33        12        22
3         123      99        1232      45
5         224      57
```

How can I do this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you elaborate on the logic between the conversions, please? Your input has only one `3`, while the output has two. Which element is supposed to end up where?

Comment: Can you show us your current code? I'm not sure if you can do it in Matlab without a `for` loop, but we may be able to help improve what you have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grouping matrix rows in terms of one column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159206/grouping-matrix-rows-in-terms-of-one-column)

Comment: @Schorsch  Shai made a big step. But I want to make the output as a one matrix. How can I merge r{1} and r{2} to a matrix B? I tried B = [r{1} ; r{2}] but failed. Maybe filling the empty cell as some number which is very very unlikely to exist in other cells such as "55555555555" will work? Then after exporting to xlsx I can mass-replace using MS excel. How can I fill those empty cells as 555555555 and make the r{1}, r{2}... as one big matrix?

Comment: possible duplicate of: [Grouping matrix rows in terms of one column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159206/grouping-matrix-rows-in-terms-of-one-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `accumarray` with a custom function

```
>> r = accumarray( A(:,1), A(:,2), [], @(x) {x'} ); %//'
 r = 
  [1x3 double]
  [1x2 double]
>> r{1}
 ans =
  1     3     9
>> r{2}
 ans =
  4     7
```

**Update:**
Converting cell `r` to a matrix `B` (accomodating further requests in comments):

```
>> [U ix iu] = unique( A(:,1) ); % see EitantT's comment
>> r = accumarray( iu, A(:,2), [], @(x) {x'} ); 
>> n = cellfun( @numel, r ); % fund num elements in each row - need for max
>> mx = max(n);
>> pad = 555555; % padding value
>> r = cellfun( @(x) [x pad*ones(1,mx - numel(x))], r, 'uni', 0 );
>> B = vertcat( r{:} ); % construct B from padded rows of r
```

Comment: +1: It's probably safer to use `unique(A(:, 1))` as subs for `accumarray`. If the column #1 values are large, you might end up with unnecessarily large arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much. But how can I merge r{1} and r{2} to a matrix B? I tried B = [r{1} ; r{2}] but failed.

Comment: And I couldn't understand what Eitan mean. How should the code of Shai change to accommodate your suggestion?

Comment: @user1849133 what should be the third element on the second row of `B`?

Comment: Well, it should be empty. Or it should be empty at least when exported to csv or xlsx using xlswrite or something.

Comment: If that's impossible, maybe filling the empty cell as some number which is very very unlikely to exist in other cells such as "55555555555". Then after exporting to xlsx I can mass-replace using MS excel.

Comment: And can the output be "1   1    3    9" and "2   4   7" rather than "1   3  9" and "4  7"? I mean the A(:,1) with duplicates removed is put in the 1st column so that it becomes clear in which index those  1,3,9 and 4,7 belong to.

Comment: @Shai Oh there was this referring system. Could you please make this as one big matrix B? Filling the empty parts as some number which is very very unlikely to exist in other cells such as "55555555555" seems to be an OK method?

Comment: @EitanT Thank you for your comment! But how should the code of Shai change to accommodate your suggestion?

Comment: Well, you should map the column #1 values to unique indices with: `[U, ix, iu] = unique(A(:, 1));` and then pass `iu` as the first parameter to `accumarray` instead of `A(:, 1)`.

Comment: @Shai I thank you very much! Very good! But I had some trouble when there were more columns in A. I wrote the updates. Thank you again!

Comment: @user1849133 why don't you ask it as a new question (with proper link for context)?

Comment: @Shai That's a good idea since we have too many comments. I wrote at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447474/matlab-to-convert-a-matrix-or-a-csv-to-put-2nd-3rd-4th-column-values-to-the-sa