# Group values in different rows by their first-column index

Tags: matlab, csv, matrix

This question is an outgrowth of [MatLab (or any other language) to convert a matrix or a csv to put 2nd column values to the same row if 1st column value is the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404892/matlab-or-any-other-language-to-convert-a-matrix-or-a-csv-to-put-2nd-column-va)

If

```
      A = [2 3 234 ; 2 44 33; 2 12 22; 3 123 99; 3 1232 45; 5 224 57]
```

### 1st column |  2nd column | 3rd column

```
2             3          234
2             44         33
2             12         22
3             123        99
3             1232       45
5             224        57
```

then running

```
    [U ix iu] = unique(A(:,1) ); 
    r= accumarray( iu, A(:,2:3), [], @(x) {x'} )
```

will show me the error

```
    Error using accumarray
    Second input VAL must be a vector with one element for each row in SUBS, or a
    scalar.
```

I want to make

### 1st col |  2nd col | 3rd col | 4th col | 5th col | 6th col| 7th col

```
2         3        234       44        33        12        22
3         123      99        1232      45
5         224      57
```

I know how to do it using for and if, but that spends too much time for big data.

How can I do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misusing `accumarray` in the solution provided to your previous question. The first parameter `iu` is the vector of indices and the second parameter should be a vector of values, of the same length. What you did here is specify a matrix as the second parameter, which in fact has twice more values than indices in `iu`.

What you need to do in order to make it work is create a vector of indices both for the second column and for the third column (they are the same indices, not coincidentally!) and specify a matching column vector of values, like so:

```
[U, ix, iu] = unique(A(:,1));
vals = reshape(A(:, 2:end).', [], 1);                    %'// Columnize values
subs = reshape(iu(:, ones(size(A, 2) - 1, 1)).', [], 1); %'// Replicate indices
r = accumarray(subs, vals, [], @(x){x'});
```

This solution is generalized for any number of columns that you want to pass to `accumarray`.

Comment: Your solution is great! Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Eitan_T Yes I voted up your answer. I wasn't clicking the up button after I got the message "you can't vote up unless you reach reputation of 15" but now I could vote up since my reputation was more than 15. Thank you for reminding me :)

Comment: @Eitan_T  I noticed a difference between what I want and your code. I tried but I could not get the output table I wrote. Your code seems to give me column-by-column rearranging. But my purpose was to row-by-row rearranging. I tried some changes but they failed. Perhaps I have to study accumarray more. Could you give me a simple fix for this?

Comment: @Eitan_T What I get is   r{1}=3    44    12    22    33   234, r{2}=1232         123          99          45, r{3}= 57   224, so the order is different.

Comment: @Eitan_T  Quite strange :(  Perhaps different versions of Matlab does different things? It is difficult to find reason. To find what the problem is, I will report to you all variables I get.

Comment: @Eitan_T   U= 2 3 5 (in column vector), ix=3 5 6 (in column vector), iu= 1 1 1 2 2 3 (in column vector), vals = 3 44 12 123 1232 224 234 33 22 99 45 57, subs = 1 1 1 2 2 3 1 1 1 2 2 3

Comment: @user1849133 Oh I see what you mean. I've amended my answer.

Comment: @Eitan_T I am sorry to reply late. Your solution works! Thank you!

Comment: @user1849133 Excellent!

Comment: @Eitan_T I posted an outgrowth of this question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667224/matlab-to-convert-a-matrix-with-respect-to-1st-col   Could you figure out how to do it? Of course I will be likely to pay more attention to your answer than answers of others :)