# MatLab to convert a matrix with respect to 1st col

Tags: matlab

This question is an outgrowth of [MatLab (or any other language) to convert a matrix or a csv to put 2nd column values to the same row if 1st column value is the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404892/matlab-or-any-other-language-to-convert-a-matrix-or-a-csv-to-put-2nd-column-va) and [Group values in different rows by their first-column index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447474/matlab-to-convert-a-matrix-or-a-csv-to-put-2nd-3rd-4th-column-values-to-the-sa)

If

```
      A = [2 3 234 ; 2 44 99999; 2 99999 99999; 3 123 99; 3 1232 45; 5 99999 57]

1st column |  2nd column | 3rd column
--------------------------------------
2             3          234
2             44         99999
2             99999      99999
3             123        99
3             1232       45
5             99999        57
```

I want to make

```
1st col |  2nd col | 3rd col | 4th col | 5th col | 6th col| 7th col
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2         3        234       44       
3         123      99        1232      45
5         57
```

That is, for each numbers in the 1st col of A, I want to put numbers EXCEPT "99999"

If we disregard the "except 99999" part, we can code as [Group values in different rows by their first-column index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447474/matlab-to-convert-a-matrix-or-a-csv-to-put-2nd-3rd-4th-column-values-to-the-sa)

```
[U, ix, iu] = unique(A(:,1));
vals = reshape(A(:, 2:end).', [], 1);                    %'// Columnize values
subs = reshape(iu(:, ones(size(A, 2) - 1, 1)).', [], 1); %'// Replicate indices
r = accumarray(subs, vals, [], @(x){x'});
```

But obviously this code won't ignore 99999.

I guess there are two ways

```
1. first make r, and then remove 99999
2. remove 99999 first, and then make r
```

Whichever, I just want faster one.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think options 1 is better, i.e. *first make r, and then remove 99999*. Having r, u can remove 99999 as follows:

```
r2 = {}; % new cell array without 99999

for i = 1:numel(r)    
    rCell = r{i};
    whereIs9999 = rCell == 99999; 
    rCell(whereIs9999) = []; % remove 99999
    r2{i} = rCell;
end
```

Or more fancy way:

```
r2= cellfun(@(c) {c(c~=99999)}, r);
```

Comment: You don't preallocate before the loop, so this might have performance issues for large cell arrays. Instead, you'd rather remove values in-place: `for k = 1:numel(r), r{k}(r{k} ~= 99999) = []; end`. Also, you forgot to put `'UniformOutput', false` in `cellfun`...

Comment: @EitanT `UniformOutput` is not needed in this case, as I return cells and there will be the same number of cells in output as in input. But preallocation is always good in performance is a factor.

Comment: I think `'UniformOutput', false` is mandatory here because you return a cell array and not a matrix.

Comment: @EtianT In this case each output from the anonymous function is a cell array. Don't need `flase` in this case.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the curly braces in the anonymous function.