# Storing blocks of vector data into an array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, for-loop, vector

I have an array in Matlab

```
 A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9;
     67 67 67 86 86 86 86 67 67]';
```

where every point in the first row of A corresponds to a "code" either `67` or `86`. I am trying to extract these blocks of `"67s"` and `"86s"` such that every time a block starts the corresponding elements are put into the 3rd dimension of a different array called X, where the .

So for e.g. in A I have 3 different blocks, so I would like to end up with an array X of size 1x9x3. And for e.g. the first `67` block I would like to have X

```
 X(1,:,1) = [1 2 3];
```

I understand that I would "fill up" this vector X using a for loop

```
for i=1:size(A,2)
  for j=1:size(A,2) %actually j should be up till the number of blocks present
    X(1,i,j) = A(1,i) 
  end
end
```

But this isn't correct or complete of course because firstly I'm unsure how to separate out the "blocks" and how to correctly "fill in" the j's in X(1,i,j). Secondly how can I get the code to recognise how many blocks there are?

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that your example data is correct? As you have it you have 4 entries for `86`.

Comment: @Suever yes, the blocks are not of equal size!

Comment: In your example, if `X` is `1x9x3`, then `X(1,:,1)` should be an array with 9 elements, hence it could not contain `[1 2 3]`. I suggest you review your example.

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro I think I'm just unable to explain what I mean clearly. Since I am separating out by blocks, within X(:,:,1) I only want the elements of the first block... which are 1 2 3.

Comment: But if `X`  is a a 3-dimensional matrix, `X(:,:,n)` will have the same number of elements for every `n`. Perhaps a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) would work better for you. You could have something like `X{1} = [1 2 3]`, and `X{2} = [4 5 6 7]` for example.

Comment: Ahh OK. But then how do I go about creating X{i}?  I need a way of identifying the blocks so that each block is an i

Comment: I've added a possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159206/grouping-matrix-rows-in-terms-of-one-column) answer:

```
>> B = accumarray([0; cumsum(diff(A(:,2)) ~= 0)] + 1, A(:,1), [], @(x) {x}, [])
```

Now you have this:

```
>> B{1}

ans =

     1
     2
     3

>> B{2}

ans =

     4
     5
     6
     7

>> B{3}

ans =

     8
     9
```